# How to make a fluid text centered box with a margin when text is too long?

Tags: html, css

I have *HTML*:

```
<header class="title">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
</header>
```

And *CSS*:

```
.title {
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 15px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    width: 42px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.title h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/EZwaQ/ :)

I want to (1) make the text center aligned when it's short but (2) don't cover the back button on the left when it's too long.

[image: example]

As you can see in that jsfiddle, I added a `margin-left` in the second example.

Is there any universal CSS way to approach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i updated your jsfiddle look at this

`jsfiddle` : http://jsfiddle.net/EZwaQ/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
.header{margin:0 15px 0 72px;} //margin-left-->42px of width and 30px of margin for back
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/EZwaQ/2/)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Then the title is not centered to the whole bar :( Looks a little weird when the text is short.